# Does Stack Overflow scrape other question sites, forums or mailing lists?

Tags: discussion, screen-scraping

I have seen some old posts on Stack Overflow that are repeated in forums and mailing lists. Does Stack Overflow scrape other question sites, forums or mailing lists?

Comment: Usually it's either the other way around, or people cross-post stuff. SO itself (and all the rest of the sites) don't scrape anything from anywhere else.

Answer (score 12):

It's usually the other way around. Anything on Stack Overflow is supposed to be posted by an actual, real person (though I am told in the comments [there have been bots in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71574/has-anyone-ever-tried-running-an-answer-bot-on-stack-overflow/283095#283095)). In a sense *this is important* since scraping wouldn't have the somewhat specific, detailed answers to actual problems that makes the network useful. There's *no* mechanism for doing so. In fact, we strongly discourage people from reproducing information

Our 'Boilerplate' Moderator message for plagiarism reads

> It has come to our attention that several of your answers consisted
>   primarily or entirely of text copied from other answers or websites.
>   We prefer not to simply copy content already available elsewhere in
>   lieu of creating something that adds value to this site specifically.
>
> Whenever possible, we prefer that posts be your own original work, but
>   when a great answer already exists elsewhere, including a small
>   passage of text from another source can be a great way to support your
>   solution. But please note that we require full attribution with a link
>   to the original author, and please be sure you are not copying content
>   without permission.

And well, taking that in mind, scraping external sites completely goes against both the spirit, and letter of our rules.

On the other hand, Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange as a whole has incredibly good search engine ratings, and really good information. People scrape *us*, and as long as the respect the CC licence all content here has, *it's fine*.

The former results in a few sites either reproducing a lot of content off the site ([there's many many questions here on scrapers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=scrapers)) or choosing to selectively highlight parts of it (*How-To Geek* has a series of articles which are more or less a condensed version of Super User's Hot Network Questions for example, which often drives a lot of traffic to specific, already popular questions).

So yeah, SE does not scrape - and actively discourages people from acting like scrapers. Other sites on the other hand, find the content here good enough to reproduce.

Comment: HowtoGeek is a great example considering it's origins

Comment: The first paragraph isn't right. [At least one bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283095/188189) as posted questions and answers.

Comment: eww. Let me correct that.