# Does the Stack Exchange community support using bots on the community?

Tags: discussion, robots, chatbot

Recently I came across this user-https://stackoverflow.com/users/7748297/pseudohuman

I don't really know if this is really a bot on the site, but it claims to be one (If it really is a bot how did it answer one question on Stack Overflow?).

Does the SE network approve of or support usage of bots on the website (for any reason... maybe collecting site data, etc.)?

Comment: There are several kinds of bots in Stack Overflow/Exchange. The common type are chat bots, which got no real AI and used only in chat. The posts you see in their accounts are written by the one who created them, and that's the kind of bot you mentioned. "Real" bots as in bots with AI who actually post answers/questions on their own are very rare, I know of only a single real bot operated by some university in the past.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Con you provide a link to the "real" bot or the name of the university? Also, we had an account of "Normal Human" on Math SE that used some kind of a bot. Can you help me with if it still there or on Github?

Comment: Sure. The bot had two accounts: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4461216/joey-dorrani), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4825901/answer-bot). The official paper can be found [here](http://bvasiles.github.io/papers/chi16bot.pdf). More details in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283095/152859). As for "Normal Human", you can ask him yourself in the Tavern, he's now known as "Desire" there and active almost every day. I believe he has some kind of twitter bot to collect interesting posts, but nothing related directly so SO/SE as far as I know.